# Using Whenever with RedMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, redmine, whenever, redmine-plugins

I am trying to set up a cron task for a model in a redmine plugin. The Whenever gem looked like the best option. Alas, it does not seem to do anything.

I have set up the gem, both in the config folder of the plugin and the primary one. I added it to the crontab (using the whenever -i command) have reset the server. 
The action was not run, and no log was generated

here is the schedule.rb  file.

```
 set :output, "/path/to/my/cron_log.log"

every 1.day, :at => '9:00 am' do
    runner "pluginMailMethod.send_emails"
end

every :thursday, :at => '4:20 pm' do
    runner "pluginMailMethod.send_emails"
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/407

Comment: (redmine contributor here)

Could you provide a sample plugin and step to reproduce ?

The `: No such file or directory` looks like an environment issue somewhere. Does whenever find ruby and your gems ? If you use RVM : whenever's RVM integration assumes a `bash -l` call will load your RVM environment correctly, which might not be the case ; if you use something else, tell us.

How and where did you run the "wheneverize" command ? Do you have a Gemfile in your plugin ?